# Как в pyqt5 получить список всех принтеров, установленных в системе?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как в интернете, так и [тут](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) никакой информации нет, как же тогда получить список установленных принтеров в системе?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Два дня искал, не мог найти! Как только задал вопрос, сразу ответ попался на глаза. 
l = QtPrintSupport.QPrinterInfo.availablePrinterNames()